# Convert URI to windows path format

Tags: javascript, uri

In Javascript I'm looking for a regex that will convert URI to Windows format, but I'm not too familiar with URI cases to form a regex.
Basically...

- `/c/myDocs/file.txt`
- `//myDocs/file.txt`

should be changed to

```
"C:\myDocs\file.txt"
```

There may be other cases that I'm unaware of. Hence needing some help. All I have so far is swapping the slashes over with a replace, but not the drive name with a regex.

```
function pathME(apath)
{
    apath = apath.replace(/\//g, "\\")
    return apath;
}
```

Regex wizards, start your engines please!

Comment: Hey Man, my solution is regex(as asked for) and copes with all drives also, and was posted before. Why didn't you like it? and is a oneliner (okay with methode chaining but still)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will cover the two cases above:

```
mystring.replace(/^\/([^\/]?)\//, function(match, drive) {
    return (drive || 'c').toUpperCase() + ':\\';
}).replace(/\//g, '\\');
```

Comment: +1 Nice approche with the function Call in the Replace Function!! *ME LIKE*

Comment: Does this properly handle unicode, e.g `%20` for spaces, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This Regex should solve your question, but could be optimized
Takes care of all Drive names with length 1:

```
   "/c/myDocs/file.txt".replace(/\//g,"\\").replace(/^(\\)(?=[^\\])/, "").replace(/^(\w)(\\)/g, "$1:\\")
  // Result is "c:\myDocs\file.txt"
```

Example two

```
"//myDocs/file.txt".replace(/\//g,"\\").replace(/^(\\)(?=[^\\])/, "").replace(/^(\w)(\\)/g, "$1:\\")
 // Result is "\\myDocs\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for any regular expressions here. You can just do it with simple string manipulation:, I think. This way you can handle errors in the input string a lot better, if you want to.

```
var newpath = apath.replace(/\//g, '\\');
var drive = null;
if (newpath.substring(0, 2) == '\\\\') { 
   drive = 'c';
   newpath = newpath.substring(1);
}
else if (newpath.substring(0, 1) == '\\') {
   drive = newpath.substring(1, newpath.indexOf('\\', 2)); 
   newpath = newpath.substring(newpath.indexOf('\\', 2));
}
if (drive != null) { newpath = drive + ':' + newpath; }
```

And on a side note: I don't know the scope of your problem, but there will be cases where this doesn't work. For example in Unix a network share would be mounted to `/any/where/in/the/filesystem` while in Windows you would need `\\remotehost\share\`, so obviously a simple conversion doesn't work here.

Comment: He's come here for advice and he got the best I have. He described a problem and I gave him a solution. No need to downvote that in my opinion. If he can come up with a reasonable argument why he *needs* a regular expression...fine, but so far I don't see the point.

Comment: Okay i went a bit over the top there. Sorry, had too much coffee today. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming C drive won't be the only drive in your path strings, so wrote a small pathME() function mimicking yours. This should cover all cases that you've mentioned.

```
function pathME(apath) {
    //Replace all front slashes with back slashes
    apath = apath.replace(/\//g, "\\");

    //Check if first two characters are a backslash and a non-backslash character
    if (apath.charAt(0) === "\\" && apath.charAt(1) !== "\\") {
        apath = apath.replace(/\\[a-zA-Z]\\/, apath.charAt(1).toUpperCase() + ":\\");
    }

    //Replace double backslash with C:\
    apath = apath.replace("\\\\", "C:\\");
    return apath;
}
```